# Почему программа не запускается через powershell?

Tags: cmd, bat, powershell

Я записал в реестр Windows 7 команду для запуска блокнота с правами Администратора. 
Она появляется в контекстном меню Windows но при нажатии на него ничего видимого не происходит.

```
powershell.exe -command Start-Process C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe -Verb RunAs
```

Если скопировать эту строчку и запустить в CMD блокнот запуститься через 13 секунд раздумья.
[image: Реестр]

Comment: А в `procexp` Марка Русиновича эту копию блокнота видит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующая команда запускает программу с правами администратора.
Для записи в реестр нужно экранировать все двойные кавычки!
Это можно сделать обратным слешем проставляя его перед каждой двойной кавычкой.
Пример записи в .reg файле

```
@="mshta vbscript:createobject(\"shell.application\").shellexecute(\"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe\",\"\",\"\",\"runas\",1)(window.close)"
```

Так она выглядит в .bat файле который запишет её уже в .reg файл.
%exec% это переменная в которую заносится путь к программе.

```
echo.@="mshta vbscript:createobject(\"shell.application\").shellexecute(\"%exec%\",\"\",\"\",\"runas\",1)(window.close)" >> Menu.reg
```

Вот так вот будет выглядеть готовая запись в реестре, после запуска .reg файла. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за команду [Daemon-5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265408/daemon-5)

Answer (score 0):

Да, первый запуск PowerShell не мгновенный, мягко выражаясь. Можете попробовать:

```
PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Command "Start-Process notepad -Verb RunAs"
```

Ну или если вас не смущает сторонняя утилита, можете скачать nircmd и закинуть ее в папку System32. Далее использовать следующую команду:

```
nircmd elevate notepad.exe "%1"
```

Comment: Я написал bat файл который создаёт файл reg для реестра. Он может создавать для любой программы запись в реестре, для дальнейшего отображения в контекстном меню. И я хотел реализовать там так-же запуск приложения с правами админа. Я не хочу использовать сторонние утилиты. Я вроде всё правильно написал а не работает.. Может через CMD как-то можно с правами админа запускать программу? Powershell.exe я так понимаю не хочет со мной дружить, только из под палки (cmd) готова работать..

Comment: НУ если PS - медленный, попробуйте другую команду: **mshta vbscript:createobject("shell.application").shellexecute("notepad.exe","","","runas",1)(window.close)**

Comment: @Daemon-5 Это команда запустит программу с правами администратора?

Comment: "Не узнаешь вкуса каши, пока не положишь её в рот"©

Comment: @Daemon-5 Нет это не сработало. Когда я запускаю файл .reg с подобной командой она просто не записывается в реестр из за того, что в нутри есть двойные кавычки. Я пробовала заменить их на одинарные, она заносится в реестр но это вызывает ошибку скрипта. @="mshta vbscript:createobject('shell.application').shellexecute('C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe','','','runas',1)(window.close)" Я не могу использовать двойные кавычки.

Comment: Странно звучит. Получается надо научиться записывать в значение ключа реестра строку с двойной кавычкой. Это уже совершенно другая проблема, которая требует научиться использовать cmd-леты **New-Item**,**New-ItemProperty**. Либо научиться передавать двойные строки в командной строке. Ни то, ни другое не представляет собой технических трудностей - даже имеются решения на **SO**.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Да я посмотрел как делать записи подобными командами в реестр. Так ведь это команды, мне нужно что-бы в reg файле была команда. Т.е. я запускаю reg и он записывает в реестр всё необходимое.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Всё я нашёл решение данной проблемы. Запостил ответ спасибо!